# Finding all shortest paths and distances using Floyd-Warshall

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, floyd-warshall

First, a little background: I'm working on building a simple graph class with basic graph algorithms (Dijkstra, Floyd-Warshall, Bellman-Ford, etc) to use as a reference sheet for an upcoming programing competition.

So far I have a functioning version of Floyd-Warshall, but the downside is that so far it's only getting me the shortest *distance value* between two nodes, not the *shortest path*.  Preferably I'd like to have the path-building take place within the algorithm itself instead of having to call another function to reconstruct it.

Here's some info on the data structures I'm using:

`vector< vector<int> > graph //contains the distance values from each node to each other node (graph[1][3] contains the length of the edge from node #1 to node #3, if no edge, the value is INF`

`vector< vector<int> > path //contains the "stepping stones" on how to reach a given node.  path[st_node][end_node] contains the value of the next node on the way from end_node -> st_node`

Here's the example graph data I'm using:

```
INF 10  INF INF INF INF
INF INF 90  15  INF INF
INF INF INF INF INF 20
INF INF INF INF 20  INF
INF INF  5  INF INF INF
INF INF INF INF INF INF
```

and here's the desired values to be in the "path" variable (gotten by running Dijkstra from each of the nodes):

```
INF  0   4   1   3   2
INF INF  4   1   3   2
INF INF INF INF INF  2
INF INF  4  INF  3   2
INF INF  4  INF INF  2
INF INF INF INF INF INF
```

Here's a link to the code I'm currently using for the algorithm: [(via PasteBin)](http://pastebin.com/KDY3qHQt).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit:* I tried [Wikipedia's code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction) to generate the path matrix and here's the result:

```
INF INF  4   1   3   4
INF INF  4  INF  3   4
INF INF INF INF INF INF
INF INF  4  INF INF  4
INF INF INF INF INF  2
INF INF INF INF INF INF
```

It kinda works but has issues when it comes to representing "single" steps.  For example, the path from node 0 to node 1 is undefined everywhere. (But nonetheless, thank you Nali4Freedom for the suggestion)

Comment: If I'm reading this right, according to the first row of `graph` there's only one edge from node #0, and it leads to node #1. So the first row (or maybe first column) of `path` should be `Inf 1 1 1 1 1`. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I see how you could get confused with that yes.  Each row in `graph` lists the edges leaving from that node whereas each row in `path` contains the path to get to `node #[row_num]`.  For example, the first row of the correct `path` chart means that to get to node 0 (row = 0) from node 5 (col = 5), the next node on the way back is node 2.  To get to node 0 from node 2 we use node 4, then node 3, then node 1, then finally at our destination with node 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huzzah!

I had a good hard stare at the results from adding Wikipedia's code snippet and I came up with an adapter to convert it's results into my results without the need of calling a separate function:

```
// Time to clean up the path graph...
for (int st_node = 0; st_node < this->size; st_node++)
{
    for (int end_node = 0; end_node < this->size; end_node++)
    {
        int mid_node = this->path[st_node][end_node];

        if (mid_node == INF)
        {
            // There is no mid_node, it's probably just a single step.
            if (this->graph[st_node][end_node] != INF)
            {
                this->path[st_node][end_node] = st_node;
            }

        } else {
            // The mid_node may be part of a multi-step, find where it leads.
            while (this->path[mid_node][end_node] != INF)
            {
                if (this->path[mid_node][end_node] == mid_node) { break; }  // Infinite loop
                if (this->path[mid_node][end_node] == INF) { break; }   // Dead end

                mid_node = this->path[mid_node][end_node];
            }

            this->path[st_node][end_node] = mid_node;

        }   // IF mid_node
    }   // FOR end_node
}   // FOR st_node
```

Essentially this compensates for when getting from node A to node B is a single step `(mid_node == INF)` by adding the edge if it existed in the original graph.  Alternately, if the node it points to is just a stepping stone to the destination node `(this->path[mid_node][end_node] != INF)` then it digs until it finds where it leads to.

Thanks for the help guys, guess I just needed someone to think out loud to!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some good info and [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction). Basically you just fill a |V|x|V| 'next' matrix where element i,j contains the index of the vertex you need to go to to get from node i to node j. The shortest path from i to j can then be gives as the path from i to next[i][j] and from next[i][j] to j. You continue to decompose the path recursively like this until you have the full path.

Comment: Trust me, I gave it a go, but the way my setup works (default values set to INF) it doesn't work properly. :\